# Getting error for regression using csv files in scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I read the data from `features.csv` file and stored in a array.
i got the classlabels of those features and stored in a textfile.
Fitting the data:

```
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(train_input, train_lab)
```

But when i use the test set i am getting same value for all the records of test data.
But if i use test set as subset from training set the O/P is exact. I am unable to know whether my model is built or not. How to overcome this problem.
This is not for classification. It is for regression.

Comment: I'm confused: you say it's not a classification problem, but you also say you have the class labels stored in a text file

Comment: It is a regresion problem. So i am predicting the time. So i have stored time as label and stored it in a file